# Higher order functions not working in casperjs

Tags: coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have function defined like this

```
casper.executeRemote = (fn,params)->
    ->
        try
            fn.apply(this,params)
        catch e
            console.log(e)

getLinks = ->
    elems = document.querySelectorAll('#pagination-flickr a')
```

and i am calling the function like below

```
casper.then ->
    all_links = @evaluate @executeRemote getLinks
    casper.log all_links,'debug'
```

However I get the below error when i try to run this in casperjs

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: fn
```

The same code works fine, if i try in a browser console(compiled js). What is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Artjom's answer. I modified the code as shown below, then it works

```
executeRemote = (fn,params)->
    ->
        try
            fn.apply(this,params)
        catch e
            console.log(e)

getLinks = ->
    elems = document.querySelectorAll('#pagination-flickr a')
    links = (link.href for link in elems)

remoteWrapper = (excRm,gL)->
        excRm=eval('('+excRm+')')
        gL=eval('('+gL+')')
        fn=excRm(gL)
        fn()

casper.on 'remote.message',(message)->
    @echo message

casper.then -> 
    all_links = @evaluate remoteWrapper, executeRemote.toString(), getLinks.toString()
    casper.log all_links,'debug'
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course they work, but not at the border to the [page context](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html):

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Thankfully there is the `toString` function on `Function`s. So, you can change your code a little to account for passing the function as a string and `eval`ing inside of the page context.

(Untested) example:

```
casper.executeRemote = (fn,params)->
    fn = eval('('+fn+')')
    try
        fn.apply(this,params)
    catch e
        console.log(e)

getLinks = ->
    elems = document.querySelectorAll('#pagination-flickr a')

casper.then ->
    all_links = @evaluate(@executeRemote, getLinks.toString())
    casper.log all_links,'debug'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did not work out of the box, but I got the idea. I could get it working as shown below